# Java stream - filter based on child item

Tags: java, java-stream

I have List of  each Person has List of . The CellPhone has brandName and modelNumber. How do I use Java stream to filter list of Person whose modelNumber equals some value. In the below code, I need to filter Persons whose modelNumber is 10

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Integer searchModel = 10;
        
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        CellPhone a1 = new CellPhone("Nokia", 10);
        CellPhone a11 = new CellPhone("Sony", 11);
        List<CellPhone> phoneList = new ArrayList<>();
        phoneList.add(a11);
        phoneList.add(a1);
        Person p1 = new Person("John", phoneList);
        
        CellPhone a2 = new CellPhone("Nokia", 10);
        CellPhone a22 = new CellPhone("Sony", 11);
        phoneList = new ArrayList<>();
        phoneList.add(a2);
        phoneList.add(a22);
        Person p2 = new Person("Doe", phoneList);
        
        CellPhone a3 = new CellPhone("Apple", 20);
        CellPhone a33 = new CellPhone("Samsung", 22);
        phoneList = new ArrayList<>();
        phoneList.add(a3);
        phoneList.add(a33);
        Person p3 = new Person("Rose", phoneList);
        
        CellPhone a4 = new CellPhone("Nokia", 10);
        CellPhone a44 = new CellPhone("Sony", 11);
        phoneList = new ArrayList<>();
        phoneList.add(a4);
        phoneList.add(a44);
        Person p4 = new Person("Kumar", phoneList);
        
        CellPhone a5 = new CellPhone("Apple", 20);
        CellPhone a55 = new CellPhone("Samsung", 22);
        phoneList = new ArrayList<>();
        phoneList.add(a5);
        phoneList.add(a55);
        Person p5 = new Person("Angel", phoneList);
        
        CellPhone a6 = new CellPhone("Apple", 20);
        CellPhone a66 = new CellPhone("Samsung", 22);
        phoneList = new ArrayList<>();
        phoneList.add(a6);
        phoneList.add(a66);
        Person p6 = new Person("Prince", phoneList);
        
        persons.add(p1);
        persons.add(p2);
        persons.add(p3);
        persons.add(p4);
        persons.add(p5);
        persons.add(p6);
        
        
        persons.stream().filter(p -> p.getPhones().stream().filter(x -> x.getModelNumber().equals(searchModel)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    
    // expected Person list is John, Doe and Kumar
    // above filter gives me an error cannot convert from list to boolean
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.filter` expects `Predicate` and your code does not have this for the outer `.filter`.

You can do it as:

```
persons.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getPhones().stream()
                    .anyMatch(x -> x.getModelNumber() == searchModel)
    ).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Note that if the return types of `getModelNumber()` is `int`, you need to use `==` instead of `.equals`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `hasPhone` function to your Person class:

```java
public boolean hasPhone(int modelNumber) {
     return phones.stream()
                 .anyMatch(phone -> phone.getModelNumber() == modelNumber);
}
```

Now just filter your persons list as follows:

```java
List<Person> result = persons.stream()
                .filter(person -> person.hasPhone(10))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Please note that `.filter(x -> x.getModelNumber().equals(searchModel)).collect(Collectors.toList())` does return a list of phones and not a boolean. You are asking for "What phones of that person have a modelNumber of 10?" when you actual want to know "Does this person own any phone with a modelNumber of 10?". This concept of asking if a person owns a phone with a specific modelNumber is, well, bound to the person itself and should therefore be included in the Person class.